# What is the best way to store data after reading from Excel?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have to read multiple excel file while running a selenium test, so using Apache POI i can read those excel files, Please advise me on which data structure i should use to store and read easily

Comment: Depends on your requirement. You can create corresponding Java classes and then create List with each row as one object. Or hashmap, totally depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know your data follows a particular structure, that can narrow your question. But generically, what you probably need is to implement some sort of:

```
class Table {
public:
    std::vector<Row> rows;
}

class Row {
public:
    std::vector<Cell> cells;
}

class Cell {
public:
     int intValue;
     double doubleValue;
     // Etc
     enum Datatype {...};
     Datatype datatype;
}
```

Now, if you know the spreadsheets contain all doubles, you can eliminate Cell and Rows can hold a vector of double. Otherwise you're going to have to be more generic about it.

Ultimately, however, this still loses data. It doesn't support formulas, for instance, or formatting. All that would be lost. That may or may not matter.

So there are a lot of questions you still need to answer to fine tune this further.